# Advantages of temporary tables in Oracle

Tags: oracle, etl

I've tried to figure out which performance impacts the use of temporary tables has on an Oracle database. We want to use these tables in our ETL process to save temporary results. At this time we are using physical tables for this purpose and truncating this tables at the beginning of the ETL process. I know that the truncate process is very expensive and therefore I thought if it would be better to use temporary tables instead.

Have anyone of you experiences if there is a performance boost by using temporary tables in this scenario?

There were only some answers on this question regarding to the SQL Server like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220151/what-is-the-comparative-speed-of-temporary-tables-to-physical-tables-in-sql). But I don't know if these recommendations also fit for the Oracle db.

It would be nice if anyone could list the advantages and disadvanteges of this feature and also point out in which scenarios this feature could be applicable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: truncate is not expensive, a delete with no condition is very expensive.
Second: do your temporary table have indexes? What about external keys?
That could affect performance.

The temporary table works more or less like Sql Server (of course the syntax is different, like global temporary table), and both are just table.
You won't get any performance gain with temporary tables against normal table, they are just the same: they have a definition on DB, can have indexes, and are logged.
The only difference is that temporary table are exclusive to your session (except for global table) and that means if multiple scripts from multiple sessions refer to the same table, every one is reading/writing a different table and they cannot locking each other (in this case you could gain performance, but I think it's rarely the case).

Comment: I thought a truncate would have the same limitations as the delete without a where condidition. Thanks for this clarification. It's not yet planed to index these temporary tables but it could be the case in the future. Would it make a difference if we would delete the temporary tables after the processing of the etl? What would be better: use temporary tables because the db drops them by it own or use classical tables and drop them manually?

Comment: I prefer temporary table (in Sql Server for small data set I usually prefer table variables because they are not written to disk, but I have no experience with the closest relative in Oracle and that's another story) because they are what they mean: they are temporary.

Comment: Also, consider that temporary table are managed by Oracle and they are automatically dropped for you in a more optimized way, you don't have to manually make a truncate before starting and at the end and are not included in backup. This could be a good reading: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/schema.htm#sthref686

Comment: Thank you for that link. I will have a look on this. Maybe we will test the performance difference of both approaches on our own. Thank you very much for sharing your experiences